# How to correctly handle SSG pagination with dynamic routes in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm fairly new to Next as a framework and I'm trying to determine how best to handle pagination.
My goal is to have urls such as:

- /category-one
- /category-one/2
- /category-one/3
- /category-two
- /category-two/2
- ... and so on

***notice the lack of a /1**

Next appears to operate through dynamic slugs in the folder/filename e.g.

```
pages/  
  [category]/  
    [page].jsx
```

However, what I'm struggling to work out, is that how I can have a page template for NON-paginated urls, and one for paginated urls, without essentially copying the file, this ending up with a bunch of extra code to maintain.

My first thought was to see if I could have say:

```
pages/
  [page].jsx  
  [category]/  
    [page].jsx
```

and extend the parent page for the child page, and just add some littles bits to handle the second part of the slug.

However, this doesn't seem to be an option.
I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find any examples that show a similar setup to what I'm seeking.

I appreciate that the simple answer would be "just have a /1 after the page one and forget the parent page template altogether", but I'd expect that a framework as robust as Next.js would be able to handle something simple like this.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the following page structure: `pages/[category]/index,js` for the template pages, and `pages/[category]/[page].js` for the paginated pages?

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I was trying to describe above, however the issue I have with that, is that I basically need to duplicate the same code between index.js and [page].js, which gives me twice as much to maintain. 
It just seemed like there would/should be a much cleaner/simpler way than this.

Comment: If you want to use the same page for both you could look into [optional catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes).

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, that looks like exactly what I need. Why I didn't come across it in the documentation I don't know!

Answer (score 1):

For anybody finding this question and having the same problem, the answer (which was provided by [juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves) in the comments) is exactly what was missing.

Look into [optional catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes).